# Передать computed в props компонента

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть кастомный компонент TheInput, где я хочу принимать prop "errors" - массив ошибок, которые возникают при валидации этого инпута.
Так получилось, что у меня есть форма, состоящая из 6-ти таких инпутов, из-за чего я решил вывести их через v-for, а в data я храню properties для каждого инпута.

```
inputs: [
    {
      label: 'E-mail*',
      model: 'email',
      type: 'email',
      required: true,
      errorComputedName: 'emailErrors',
    },
    {
      label: 'Номер телефона*',
      model: 'phone',
      type: 'text',
      required: true,
      mask: '+###########',
      errorComputedName: 'phoneErrors',
    },
    {
      label: 'Пароль*',
      model: 'password',
      type: 'password',
      required: true,
      errorComputedName: 'passwordErrors',
    },
  ],
```

Передача props'ов:

```
<the-input
    v-for="(input, inputIndex) in inputs"
    :key="inputIndex"
    v-model="formFields[input.model]"
    :label="input.label"
    :type="input.type"
    :mask="input.mask"
    class="mt-8 last:mt-0"
    :errors="$options.computed[input.errorComputedName]"
  />
```

Как видно на примере, я пробовал передавать через $options.computed - объект, состоящий из computed свойств этого компонента. Но внутрь компонента TheInput таким образом передается не результат вычислений computed, а сама функция. $options.computedinput.errorComputedName в этом случае не помогло.

Пример самого computed:

```
computed: {
...mapGetters({
  validationErrorList: 'errors/getValidationErrorList',
}),
emailErrors() {
  const errors = []
  if (this.$v.email.$dirty && !this.$v.email.required)
    errors.push(this.validationErrorList.required)
  if (this.$v.email.$dirty && !this.$v.email.email)
    errors.push(this.validationErrorList.email)
  return errors
},
```

},

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете написать маленький метод, которые будет получать значение по имени свойства

```
getComputedByName(name) {
  return this?.[name];
}
```

Другой вариант, хранить список ваших инпутов в комьютеде а не в `data`, тогда вам не придется хранить имя компьютеда, вы сможете использовать сразу значения, так как они уже доступны.